# MongoDB/mongosh, how do I insert a timestamp as a formatted string?

Tags: mongodb

Experimenting with mongo.

on document creation I want to add a timestamp to the document.
The following works in principle:

```
db.test3.users.insertOne(
  {
    name: "Bob",
    timestamp: new Date()
  }
);

db.test3.users.find({_id :ObjectId("639c8084d33ebcebf19ad4a2")})
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("639c8084d33ebcebf19ad4a2"),
    name: 'Bob',
    timestamp: ISODate("2022-12-16T14:28:20.449Z")
  }
]
```

But now I want to insert it as a string with a specific format.
Co-pilot suggested the following:

```
    db.test3.users.insertOne({
        name: "Bob",
        timestamp: {
              $dateToString: {
                format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L",
                date: new Date()
                }
            }
        })
```

But that doesn't work, it just saves the command as the value, it does not "execute" the command:

```
 db.test3.users.find({_id :ObjectId("639c8173d33ebcebf19ad4a3")})
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("639c8173d33ebcebf19ad4a3"),
    name: 'Bob',
    timestamp: {
      '$dateToString': {
        format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L',
        date: ISODate("2022-12-16T14:32:19.333Z")
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I'm obviously missing something.  Please advise

Comment: You should **never** store date values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects as in your first statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to insert a string into the database, then you should pass in a document that contains a string value for the desired field. For example:

```
> db.test3.users.insertOne({
  name: "Bob",
  timestamp: (new Date()).toString()
});
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: ObjectId("639c88130ba9e22104ea9213")
}

> db.test3.users.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("639c88130ba9e22104ea9213"),
    name: 'Bob',
    timestamp: 'Fri Dec 16 2022 09:00:35 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)'
  }
]
```

There are a few additional items to point out. First, Co-pilot is basically attempting to show you how to do the date to string conversion *in the database*.  For example, here we are adding a field with the string representation of the date during an aggregation that reads from the collection:

```
> db.foo.find()
[ { _id: 1 } ]
test> db.foo.aggregate([
  {
    '$addFields': {
      timestamp: {
        '$dateToString': {
          format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L',
          date: ISODate("2022-12-16T14:32:19.333Z")
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
[ { _id: 1, timestamp: '2022-12-16 14:32:19.333' } ]
```

You can similarly use [the `$dateToString` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) to convert existing data:

```
> db.foo.find()
[ 
  { _id: 1, timestamp: ISODate("2022-12-16T15:06:30.881Z") } 
]

> db.foo.aggregate([{ $addFields: { timestamp: { '$dateToString': { format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L', date: "$timestamp" } } } }])
[ 
  { _id: 1, timestamp: '2022-12-16 15:06:30.881' } 
]

> db.foo.aggregate([{ $addFields: { stringtimestamp: { '$dateToString': { format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L', date: "$timestamp" } } } }])
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    timestamp: ISODate("2022-12-16T15:06:30.881Z"),
    stringtimestamp: '2022-12-16 15:06:30.881'
  }
]
```

My earlier command does the string conversion "client side" in Javascript before the document is sent to the database.

The other thing to note is that `db.test3.users` isn't standard naming. In particular this results in `test3.users` being the collection name. That is separately appended with some additional database name. For example:

```
> db.test3.users
test.test3.users
```

It's not that you can't do it this way, just most of the time the collection name is a single word.

Edit: A third thing I forgot to mention is that it's usually not best practice to store dates as strings. Querying on them in that format is usually not as flexible or efficient.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the pointers.
That gets me there is 2 steps:
`
  db.foo.insertOne({
    name: "Bob",
    timestamp:  new Date()
    });


  db.foo.aggregate([{ $addFields: { timestampString: { '$dateToString': { format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L', date: "$timestamp" } } } }])
`

Is there a way to do it in one step?

Comment: Does the first code snippet in the answer not work on your side? And just to clarify - aggregation operators such as `$dateToString` are not typically used when inserting data (`upsert` being a bit of an exception). Also the `.aggregate()` you mention just modifies the object(s) being returned to the client, it does not persist anything in the database.

Comment: Ok, I got fooled by the output of `.aggregate()` looking like the result I wanted.
So I can pull a  `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L'` value from a timestamp, but it doesn't let me format the timestamp as a string on insert.   I know I trying to make it work "my way" instead of the way it's supposed to be used.   I'll keep picking at it.

Comment: I think I'm just confused about what you are trying to do and why. There are ways to use `$dateToString` to format information when it is inserted, [here is a playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XynLZOXF443) which I can add to the answer if it's helpful. But that's not what it is _for_. The client is generally responsible for defining, constructing, and formatting the document to be inserted prior to sending it to the database for persistence. That's why using doing this with Javascript (via `.toString()`) in the shell was shown as the first example

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is the MySQL equivalent of inserting a  value of `now(4)`

Comment: Having database and/or collections names with periods is not that unusual. It is used by several MongoDB internal tables, see [System Collections](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/system-collections/). Once I read this is even recommended - but I don't remember where I read it. You can access them with `db.getSiblingDB('test.test3').getCollection('user.active').find(...)`